# Какой вариант создания связей таблиц лучше?

Tags: mysql, архитектура

Есть таблица объектов `object` с полями (id, name, address_id, contact_id и тд). Хочу создать связанную с объектом таблицу `contact` с полями (phone, site, email).
Т.к. контакты (phone, site и email) у объекта могут быть несколько, то можно либо создать еще 3 таблицы (`phone`, `site`, `email`), либо объединить несколько контактов в одно поле через запятую. Какой вариант лучше? если есть еще лучше, напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Оба хуже. Вам нужна связующая таблица, примерно таким вот образом: `object(id, name, address_id)`, `contact(id, phone, site, email)`, `object_contact(object_id, contact_id)`

Comment: Цитата: `contact(id, phone, site, email)`, А, если будет нужно добавить другие виды контактов? Например: почтовый адрес, Skype, ICQ и т.д. Куда их в таком случае сохранять?

Comment: @Streletz Туда же, в `contact`, это же все атрибуты одной сущности "контакт". Лучше, конечно, это все предусмотреть на этапе проектирования базы, а не решать внезапно в ходе разработки "а давайте-ка мы будем хранить еще и клички всех домашних питомцев контакта"...

Comment: Все-таки уж лучше предусмотреть возможность добавления дополнительных контактов. Чтоб потом не мучаться

Comment: А, я, кажется, понял в чем загвоздка: @Streletz полагает, что каждый вид контакта — это отдельная сущность, то есть к примеру, email и Skype никак не связаны. Я же понял задачу так, что каждый контакт — это сущность с набором атрибутов — телефоном, е-мэйлом, и т.д. То есть, если мы хотим связаться с конкретным контактом, мы можем выбрать подходящий способ из набора. В схеме же Streletz с объектом может быть связаны email и телефон, но нет информации, один ли это тот же человек (или организация), или разные..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант.

Создать таблицу `TypesOfContacts` и заполнить её разновидностями контактных данных (`phone`, `site`, `email`, etc.).

А, в таблице `Contacts` сделать связь с таблицами `Object` и `TypesOfContacts`. Например так: `id`, `Object_id`, `Type_id`, `Contact`.

Подобное решение позволяет наиболее оптимальным образом решить данную задачу (ИМХО).

Comment: Да, думаю так будет лучше. Просто проект маленький, думал через запятую в одно поле впихнуть. А как вы думаете через запятую объединять это извращение? ))

Comment: @Азик, какой бы проект ни был (маленький, средний, большой)  решение должно быть эффективным. "Объединение через запятую" автоматически порождает совершенно лишние операции и противоречит основным принципам построения БД.